# Dropdown Rollout with different heights: setting height to auto breaks the rolldown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now I have the following fiddle:

```
body, * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

li {
  height: 100px;
}
#two {
    height: 0em;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition-property: height;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper:hover #two {
    height: 4em;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ehu2cxe2/

This seems to work, however, in my actual project I set the dropdown menu height by however tall the children are, they all have different heights so that's why I can't give them all a fixed height of, say, 4em.

I tried to change this to `height:auto` on hover, but this makes the whole thing break. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you know about how tall the children will be, you can use `max-height` instead.

```css
body, * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#two {
    max-height: 0em;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition-property: height;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper:hover #two {
    max-height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="one">(content)</div>
    <div id="two">
        <ul>
            <li>Menu1</li>
            <li>Menu2</li>
            <li>Menu3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or using js/jquery, you can get the rendered list height and apply that as the height to `transition`

```js
var h = $('#two ul').outerHeight(),
    $two = $('#two'),
    $wrapper = $('.wrapper');

$wrapper.hover(function() {
 $two.css('height',h);
}, function() {
 $two.css('height','0');
});
```

```css
body, * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#two {
    height: 0em;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition-property: height;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="one">(content)</div>
    <div id="two">
        <ul>
            <li>Menu1</li>
            <li>Menu2</li>
            <li>Menu3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also use `$.slideToggle()` but I prefer keeping the animation/transition in CSS.

```js
var $twoUl = $('#two ul'),
    $wrapper = $('.wrapper');

$wrapper.hover(function() {
 $twoUl.stop().slideToggle();
});
```

```css
body, * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#two {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#two ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="one">(content)</div>
    <div id="two">
        <ul>
            <li>Menu1</li>
            <li>Menu2</li>
            <li>Menu3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using percentages for `.wrapper` with `max-height: 100%`, you can skip the `javascript` and keep it all `css`. This way you can set your `list` elements to as many different heights as you need.

```css
 body, * {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
 }
 .wrapper {
     border: 1px solid black;
 }
 #two {
     max-height: 0em;
     overflow: hidden;
     transition-property: height;
     transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 }
 .wrapper:hover #two {
   max-height: 100%;
 }

 li:nth-child(1) {
   height: 2.5em;
   line-height: 2.5em;
   background-color: lightgrey;
 }

 li:nth-child(2) {
   height: 1.5em;
   line-height: 1.5em; 
   background-color: grey;  
 }

 li:nth-child(3) {
   height: 3.1em;
   line-height: 3.1em; 
   background-color: dimgrey;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="one">(content)</div>
    <div id="two">
        <ul>
            <li>Menu1</li>
            <li>Menu2</li>
            <li>Menu3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please put jsfiddle for your suggested solution